# The specified deps.json '$$$' does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, project.json

I am rather new to the .NET Core, and I got a .NET Core WebAPI project MyWebApp,
also, i have .Net Core Class Library project MyLib using EntityFrameworkCore

When i try to use Add-Migration, i get the error
The specified deps.json [...\MyWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\MyWebApp.deps.json] does not exist

Inspecting the folder, I noticed I have this a file in [...\MyWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\MyWebApp.deps.json]

but i really can't figure what i am supposed to do to resolve this.

myWebApi project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  "ShopManager": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": ""
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the review

Comment: Remove `runtimes` section from `project.json`. As soon as you do not use other runtimes - it's useless.

Also, where is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` packages, why they are not listed in dependencies?

Comment: the EFCore.* are on the class lib. and when i remove the RT section i get an error requiring it for .NetCore.App dependency

Comment: Remove `runtimes` and rewrite dependency as `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.1.0" }`. It's about [deployment model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/) and I had some issues developing in "wrong" depl. type.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks, it works, please formulate it as an answer, if you can elaborate a little bit about the dependency types, because from Microsoft's tutorials, I still don't understand what is the differences and why is it needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runtimes` section in `project.json` looks suspicious. As soon as you build for one runtime only - there is no need to use it.

Remove it and rewrite dependency from `"Microsoft.NETCore.App":"1.1.0"` to `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.1.0" }`.

This will change your app deployment model from "self-contained" (can run on specific platform even without framework) to "framework-dependent" (may run on any platform with framework installed). Details [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/).

Comment: what if i did need to target multiple platform?

Comment: You target multiple platforms already. You target ALL platforms where .NET Core is available without `runtimes`. Runtimes are needed when you want to make "self-contained" distribs of your app (with .NET Core inside), able to run without installing .NET Core on target machine. And if you want this... you should wait for stable tooling (currently you are using preview-4 I guess).

Comment: Hey @Dmitry, am using a Mac, but can't see the `project.json` file. And the .net core SDK am using is version **2.2**

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris SDK v2.2 is the reason why there is no more `project.json` in your project :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2017, I copied all the files including the dll's from the bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0 to the bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp1.0

The scaffolding wasn't working correctly until I copied the files in the bin folder. I am not sure what the MCD folder does but for some reason the scaffolding process looks in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue during a conference workshop today. After running `dotnet ef database update -v` to get verbose output and carefully inspecting the paths there were used, I discovered that I had an environment variable set on my Mac that was causing the issue.

If you have `PROJECTDIR` set inside your environment, the `dotnet` command may use this to resolve paths and if it does, it will most likely do it in an unexpected manner. Therefore, remove this environment variable from the shell/environment where you are doing your .Net core work.

Comment: Am still suffering from this issue but I have no `PROJECTDIR` env on my MAC

Comment: Using your comment as a starting point, I remembered I had the Development environment variable set, and no corresponding appsettings.development.json file. As soon as I added that it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized it was due to having inconsistent build targets in projects.  This is what fixed it for me:

1. Delete all `bin` and `obj` folders
2. Edit project files and solution file to ensure build targets match (e.g. only have `debug|x64` and `release|x64` everywhere)
3. Re-open visual studio and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem when I had multiple projects, even though I had selected my Api project as the default project in PMC, it still didn't work. I had to configure multiple startup projects and it was resolved.