# The specified deps.json does not exist on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Am having a challenge while running, migrations with **entity framework MVC**  on Mac, am using CLI with an SDK of .net version 2.2.

Below is the command am using :

`dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration`

But am getting this error :

> The specified deps.json
>   [/Users/idrislutaaya/Desktop/Workspace/LibraryManagement/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/LibraryManagement.deps.json]
>   does not exist

Tried some previous solutions here but no luck e.g [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591995/the-specified-deps-json-does-not-exist)

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Do you use such a file afayk? Maybe you could add it there.

Comment: No, what is that please @Nikolaus?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on Mac by uninstalling all the `dotnet` **SDK versions** I had, then after I installed only one version (2.2.300).

I the versions were conflicting.